# First item in horizontal list float left, remaining items align to the right

Tags: css

I have the following HTML and I would like for the first item to align to the left, and then the remaining three items to align to the right as a group.

I don't want to use float:right on those three because then they would have to appear in the incorrect order in the HTML.

Is there a way to apply a margin-left to the 2nd list item so that it will always force itself and the group of three to the right? See attached image for reference.

```
<ul class="overview">
  <li class="title">Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
  <li>Some text</li>
</ul>
```

[image: 1st li item to left, others in group aligned right]

Comment: You could use hard widths for the elements, and use a margin-right for the .title element, that'd do the trick :)

Answer (score 0):

If being semantic is not important for you then you can use `table`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you would have a container element around that list. If so, something like the following might meet your needs.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        position: relative;
        width: 600px;
        padding: 10px;
        border: 1px solid #f00;
    }
    .overview {
        text-align: right;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .overview li {
        display: inline;
        width: 100px;
        height: 20px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        text-align: left;
    }
    .overview li.title {
        position: absolute;
        left: 10px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <ul class="overview">
        <li class="title">Some text</li>
        <li>Some text</li>
        <li>Some text</li>
        <li>Some text</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```